# Docker build error, archive/tar: sockets not supported

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker and trying to build an image.
I succeeded in doing that with the Docker commit command, but when I'm trying to do it with Dockerfile I get this errors:

```
shim@shim-Inspiron-5570:~$ sudo docker build -t shim/debian .
[sudo] password for shim: 
ERRO[0014] Can't add file /home/shim/.ServiceHub/bc1be858c1/116f2fb4b7 to tar: archive/tar: sockets not supported 
ERRO[0014] Can't add file /home/shim/.ServiceHub/bc1be858c1/11a6628921 to tar: archive/tar: sockets not supported 
ERRO[0014] Can't add file /home/shim/.ServiceHub/bc1be858c1/2cb20241cd to tar: archive/tar: sockets not supported 
ERRO[0014] Can't add file /home/shim/.ServiceHub/bc1be858c1/4964606154 to tar: archive/tar: sockets not supported 
ERRO[0014] Can't add file /home/shim/.ServiceHub/bc1be858c1/bc1be858c1 to tar: archive/tar: sockets not supported 
^Cnding build context to Docker daemon  1.725GB
```

The Docker file looks like this:

```
FROM debian:shim
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git
RUN apt-get install -y vim
```

I'm using Ubuntu DeskTop 18.04
Can some one help me with it?

Answer (score 14):

It looks like your `Dockerfile` is probably in `/home/shim/`?

When you do `docker build .`, docker will tar up the contents of the current directory and send it to the docker daemon. It looks like some of the files in `/home/shim/.ServiceHub` are actually sockets, so this operation fails.

Best practice is to have the Dockerfile in its own, isolated, directory to avoid stuff like this.

Also, I suggest having a read through [dockerfile_best-practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/), in particular the bit about `RUN` & `apt-get`

Answer (score 4):

For this particular example, you should not have `Dockerfile` in `/home/shim`.

In the general case of a socket (`*.sock`) file in your project, you can add `*.sock` to your [.dockerignore](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I also face the same issues and got to know the reason from this Quection. My Dockerfile is restarting MySQL in a step and it creates a file called mysqld.sock which is a giving above error while building image.
If that is your case then you can add .sock file in repo itself and then use it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer is late , but in my case the cause was the same project is open in visual studio , so only closing that did the trick for me

Answer (score -1):

The errors appear if we start the command `docker build` in the home folder. My Dockerfile is placed in a subfolder, and calling `docker build -f /home/$USER/mydocker/Dockerfile` from /home/$USER will cause the error too.